# How do I markup IDS-described characters in HTML?

Tags: html, unicode, cjk

What would be the best way to markup in HTML Chinese characters that *Unicode* does not have? *Unicode* provides us the way to **describe** such characters, that is, [*Ideographic description sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideographic_Description_Characters_(Unicode_block)). But how about HTML? I wonder if there's any way to properly **markup** and render them (based on the corresponding IDSes if possible) in HTML, in a way that such a sequence be considered to be a single character.

---

Let me give you an example for the better explanation; *MediaWiki* has [an extension for this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Ids), and the syntax is as follows:

```
<ids>⿺辶⿴宀⿱珤⿰隹⿰貝招</ids>
```

Comment: Markup in HTML, for what purpose? You can use the Unicode way, but it will depend on what you do with that HTML next. If the purpose is to show this HTML in a web browser, for example, then it's the browser which needs supporting this notation.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT currently there is no HTML extension or XML namespace to mark up text with IDS.

The idea is flawed from the start, you cannot force a user agent to render a sequence with IDS as a character. There is no support for this behaviour out of the box until you [spec it out](https://whatwg.org/).

You could port that MW extension from Java to JavaScript in order to run it in the browser, perhaps text output instead of images is possible, too. (I haven't checked.) In that case, special mark-up should generally not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

IDS is already well-distinguishable from the normal text, and can be located and rendered using JavaScript without explicitly marked up in prior.

This is an implementation of [my project](https://jicheng.tw/hanzi):

```css
p { font-size: 2.5em; }
```

```html
<script>
var jchanzi = {
  conf: {
    autoProcess: true, // truthy to auto-process document body after the document is loaded
    imageAutoResize: true, // auto-resize the generated image with CSS to be same size as the original text
    imageSize: 40, // size of the (non-dynamically) generated image, in pixels, or negative for auto-detection
    imageSizeMin: 40, // minimum size of the generated image, in pixels
    imageSizeMax: 120, // maximum size of the generated image, in pixels
    fontColor: "auto", // color of the strokes of the generated image, in hex RRGGBBAA, or "auto" for auto-detection
    fontName: "", // font name of the generated image, "m" for Ming, "k" for Kai, "s" for Sung, or falsy for auto-determination (by other parameters)
    bgColor: "transparent", // background color of the generated image
    linkInfo: true, // add info link for the generated image if it's known in the database
    convertIds: true, // truthy to convert IDS
    convertIdsDynamic: 1, // whether to generate dynamic image from IDS: 0: never, 1: if unknown in the database, 2: always
    convertIdsDynamicAdvanced: 2, // generate dynamic image from which IDS: 0: never for surrounding and overlaying IDS, 1: never for overlaying IDS, 2: always
    convertIdsDynamicSize: -1, // size of the dynamically generate image, in pixels, or negative for auto-detection
    convertUnicode: 3, // generate image for what unicode chars: 1: ExtB+, 2: plus ExtA, 3: plus Kanxi radical and CJK stroke chars
    convertUnicodeDisplayable: false // convert chars matching convertUnicode even if it can be displayed in the browser
  }
};
</script>
<script src="https://jicheng.tw/hanzi/common/jchanzi.js"></script>

<p><b>Known IDS:</b> ⿰釒音、⿱堆十、⿰氵䍃、⿰魚叚、⿱⿲土白匕几</p>
<p><b>Dynamic:</b> ⿰合文、⿱井蛙、⿲彳貝亍、⿳宀珤鬼、⿴囗幹、⿵門鬼、⿶凵每、⿷匚防、⿸疒武、⿹飞肺、⿺廴火、⿻工賏；⿱⿰天人⿰合一、⿺辶⿳宀珤⿲隹貝招</p>
```

IDS rendering for the whole page can be initiated by simply setting `autoProcess` to true. Alternatively, `jchanzi.processElement(someElement)` can be explicitly called to render IDSes in the specific element. `jchanzi.unprocessElement(someElement)` can be called to unrender.

The backend server holds a database for several charsets. By default, an IDS is converted to the corresponding char image if known; otherwise it's converted to a dynamically generated image (using canvas). This behavior can be tweaked via the configs, as described above.

Current implementation is rather naive, though. Precise calculation of strokes is not yet done. Maybe some SVG-based technique would work better.